# why grub does not appear on startup / how activate grub?

Tags: grub2, system-installation, startup

I installed Ubuntu on a clean disk and afterwards, I installed some other Linux distribution.

I don't see the GRUB menu with options to choose between operating systems at boot time, Ubuntu just boots.

How can I get GRUB to start showing the options?

Comment: Search this site for howto restore grub. There are many questions, and many good answers.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer here on the site. I just needed to run

```
sudo update-grub
```

and the GRUB menu appears with all options